# Is it possible for Multiple UIViewControllers to Share the same code?

Tags: objective-c

I'm making a app with mutiple view controllers, one moves on to the next and once the user moves on to the next view there is no need to go back.

I have created the .m .h files for the view controllers that I need to play sounds on.

What I would like help with is disabling copy/paste/define in UITextview which I know how to do (and works fine) using

```
@interface MyUITextView : UITextView {
}
@end

@implementation MyUITextView
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
return NO;
}
```

Is there a way of using this code once with out creating .m .h files for each and every uiveiwcontroller?
Or will Xcode allow me to assign the same name to more than one uiveiwcontroller and use the same piece of code?

Is it possible to write it into the AppDelegate for every UITextview on different controllers?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to duplicate any code.  If you're making your UI using xib files or a storyboard, just set the class name of any text views that you want to have behave this way to `MyUITextView` in Xcode's Identity inspector.

Comment: I guess you type faster than me :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks thought there must be a easier why than renaming every controll and txt view thanks I will try that now :)

Comment: Thought Xcode might throw up a fit of errors, so simple thanks again

Comment: Hi I'm now getting 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386. ! Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) I have not touched the project since changing every view controller's textfield class names to the same name "MyUITextview". Strange because it ran fine before. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: What's the symbol it's complaining about?

Comment: Duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ MyUITextView in :

Comment: Are you importing the MyUITextView implementation instead of just the interface somewhere?  Which .o files does it say the symbol is in?

Comment: All I have done is change every uitxtview class in the identity inspector to MyUITextview which was what you said Xcode would allow right? Though that code is part of another views code.

Comment: And it says the symbols in two files that I have created .m .h files to play sounds at the push of a button.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error message?  Also, is the code you posted what MyUITextview.h looks like or is that a combination of what's in the .h/.m?

Comment: What's weird is that the error is coming from the linker, which means a code problem.  When you said all you did was update the identity inspector, I assume you also had to add some imports in the view controller files.  That's a more likely source for this message.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can I email it to you?

Comment: That's both the .m and .h code looks like just to show what's on each file.

Comment: I just want to say thanks for your help Phillip, I loaded a backup copy of my project and went through and changed every txt veiw again checking the linkers and found the error and deleted it before Xcode flagged it up.